# Git with Qt on Mac

Tags: git, qt, qt-creator

I've installed Git and Qt Creator recognizes it and can setup a repository fine. However when I go to the commit screen, I get this:

[image]

Note the actual commit button is not available. When I then close that window, it gives me this:

[image]

Anyone know why?

Comment: Just a thought - is there a textbox where you can enter a commit message? Usually git prevents commits that have empty commit message.

Comment: Did you enter a commit message? Epic Cancel/No/Yes dialog btw...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that Git requires a comment to be added before you can commit.